# Can a Centos 7 OpenVZ Container run on a Centos 6 Node

Tags: centos, openvz

Since OpenVZ isn't actually virtualization and just a container would there be issues setting up a CentOS 7 container on a Node that is only running CentOS 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use CentOS 6 and Virtuozzo 4.7 with CentOS 7 containers, OpenVZ almost the same as Virtuozzo, so it should work. It was not supported by Virtuzzo, but works without big problems, there was only several issues with `systemd` after executing `yum update` inside containers, which was solved by host reboot.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for this information. I was having issues with `systemd` after doing the initial `yum update` and was unable to use `systemctl`. I will get the host node rebooted and hope this solves my issues as well.

Comment: I've got it working now, my Centos 7 container is running on a Centos 6 node. Though im just curious did you ever get `systemctl` to work? Mine just outputs `Failed to list units: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out`

Comment: @Analog, it could be [this bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1961). But we doesn't have any issues with systemctl, everything works.

Comment: @Analog also I find old thread, we have issue, when `vzdummy-systemd` rpm was not installed inside container. May be that cause your issue.

Answer (score 0):

We run Virtuozzo 6.0.12 and 7.0.10 clusters and host both CENTOS 6 & 7 containers on both, so the answer is "YES" but depends on what you are running on the host node. I think we even have a couple of Ubuntu CT's as well.